# Get the Profit Percentage between Entry Price and Exit Price in TradingView

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v5

I'm building an indicator that opens a trade at a certain condition and should close it at a certain position.

In TradingView you can use a tool that automatically defines the Long or Short Position profit percentage as shown in this example.

[image: Precentage between Entry and Exit]

I set a condition of entry

```
entryCond = k > 0 and d > 0 and k < d and bbr > 0 and macd > 0 and signal > 0 and macd > signal and mf < 30 and cci < 0
```

And now I'm setting a condition for exit

```
exitCond = k > d and k > 80 and d > 80 and bbr > 1 and mf > 80 and cci > 100
```

I want to calculate the price of Exist minus the Price of Entry and convert it into a percentage to get a value like in screenshot 6.99

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you are building an `indicator` you need to do the calculations yourself.

The formula is `percentage = math.abs(((exit_price - entry_price) / entry_price) * 100)`

You need to store your entry and exit prices in a `var` variable so they would keep their values each iteration and update them when you enter a new position.

For strategies, one can use the built-in variable `strategy.closedtrades.profit`.

Comment: Hi, but how to get the `exit_price` and `entry_price` at first then do the calculation

Comment: Well, you should know that better than I do. You know your entry and exit conditions. Save the price in a `var` once your entry and exit conditions are `true`. For example, `entry_price := entryCond ? close : entry_price`.